# How to know what field was changed in a MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I have two tables: EMPLOYEE and DEPARTMENT. They have the following description.

```
EMPLOYEE: NAME, SSN, SALARY, DNO
DEPARTMENT: NAME, DNO, TOTAL_SAL
```

SSN is the primary key of EMPLOYEE and DNO is the primary key of DEPARTMENT. EMPLYEE.DNO is a foreign key that references DEPARTMENT.DNO. EDEPARTMENT.TOTAL_SAL is a derivated field that stores the sum of the salaries of the employees of a given department.

I would like to develop triggers for keeping the TOTAL_SAL up to date.

For example, I have the following trigger that keeps the TOTAL_SAL up to date when a new amployee is inserted.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER total_sal_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE DEPARTMENT
  SET TOTAL_SAL=TOTAL_SAL+NEW.SALARY
  WHERE DEPARTMENT.DNO=NEW.DNO;
END|
DELIMITER ;
```

However, TOTAL_SAL can change also in other 3 events:

```
1-When the salary of some employee is changed.
2-When the department of some employee is changed.
3-When some employee is removed.
```

For covering 1 and 2, I was trying to develop a trigger that fires when UPDATE events happen on the table EMPLOYEE. That is, I was trying to develop a single trigger for both cases. But, for doing that, I need to know which field of the employee was changed. If the department was changed, I need to do something. If the salary was changed, it is necessary to do something else.

Is there any way to know wha was the field changed in the UPDATE event that fires the trigger?

Is there another way to implement triggers for covering the events 1 and 2?

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

Thank you in advance.
Best regards.